# What would be a good quote or saying that says that "good quality is easily apparent?"

Tags: expressions, vocabulary, quotes

I'm trying to express that it's easy to tell when something is high quality. What would be a word, or better yet, a quote from literature, that expresses this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Qualities shine from afar, defects from up close." (Victor Hugo)

Comment: Thank you, what novel would that be from?

Comment: This quote is from Victor Hugo's "Post-Scriptum de Ma Vie" ("A Postscript to My Life"). Here's the original quote in French: "On voit les qualités de loin et les défauts de près."

Answer (score 2):

There is an old expression,

> The cream rises to the top.

While it is literally true that cream will float over milk in a raw dairy product, it can also be used figuratively to mean that excellence is easily recognized among the normal or substandard.